# Visually distinguish code highlighting tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Recently I'm encountering more and more questions that contain a significant amount of code but due to the poor/lazy choice of tags, the code is usually not highlighted. When the question contains just a couple of lines of simple code, I don't mind. But for complicated pieces (like NgRx effects) it's quite difficult to read them and in such cases I often suggest an edit, adding the `typescript` tag.

The question is, would it be possible to visually distinguish the tags that trigger code highlight? Or have a theme as a suggestion in a special group? I'm aware that this calls for some major updates but it would be nice to have feature. Some questions with tons of poorly formatted code without highlight, just ask to be ignored.

Comment: I'd find this to be useful when looking at suggested edits. If there's already a language tag that makes code highlighted, there's even less need to change the code markdown. At present there no highlighting at all in suggested edits reviews, so we're all down to just guessing.

Comment: Related: *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-wok/184109#184109)* - *"Visit that tag's wiki page. Click a tag (such as "[javascript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)"), then click "[Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)", and* ***the language hint (if any) that is currently being used for that tag*** *will be displayed at the very bottom, below the buttons for the wiki:"* (my emphasis)

Answer (score 6):

I really like this idea, it would be nice to know exactly which tags have a highlighter without having to navigate to the bottom of their respective wiki page, since that's the only place this information lives (to my knowledge), which is pretty buried and out of the way.

---

In the meantime, don't blame the tags or lazy OPs so much for bad highlighting, blame [Stack Exchange's poor tag-highlighter implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/stop-guessing-auto-detecting-a-language-when-you-know-it-will-be-incorrect). The current behavior... has a lot of room for improvement, completely within SE's control.

To compensate, any time you discover an incorrectly-highlighted code block that you want to fix, use the ```` ```lang-[language] ```` specifier above the block, which will specify a language *directly*, rather than aliasing it to whatever the tag is set to with ```` ```[tag] ````.

This is really important for languages like TypeScript, because [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) is set to use the *JavaScript* highlighter, **not** the TypeScript one (which [does exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#language-codes-currently-available-on-stack-exchange-anwi)).

Answer (score 2):

I think adding a tag for the sake of source code highlighting is an abuse of the tagging system. As you are editing the question anyway, the preferred way should be adding a language hint.

If code fences (```` ``` ````) are already used, just add the language hint right after the opening backticks:

````
``` lang-typescript
````

Otherwise, if the code is indented 4 spaces just change that too.

Comment: I admit, it's a good point. Still, it's bit confusing that adding correct tag will actually enforce code highlight. Personally, I consider language tag a must so for me it seemed natural. Should that tag highlight functionality be removed then?

Comment: No, because it still aids in default recognition. Hints are primarily used where there's a need to distinguish between several languages, such as in certain android questions. As a "worst-case" scenario, Android questions can contain Java, Kotlin, _and_ XML, which may or may not be highlighted in the correct language. The language recognition gets weird when there's extra languages, but it otherwise works well. I don't see a reason to remove either option

Comment: If you know what  language you want, then **default to using `\`\`\`lang-[language]` instead**. This is *really* important with Typescript, for example, because `\`\`\`-typescript` (the [typescript] *tag* hint) [maps to the *JavaScript* highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/info#prev-value), while `\`\`\`lang-typescript` maps to TypeScript directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see the highlight language indicated, but I don't think the color of tags is the way to go. It would not be clear enough what the color was for, and the rules are a bit too complicated:

- Two code highlight tags on a question make the highlighter use "default".
- The tag name isn't always the highlight language. For example, I think [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) is actually default highlighting.

I would prefer to just be told what language the code is being highlighted as, and why (so you know when a tag is highlighting it vs when it's been set by hand). This could be shown above the code block.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294965/5846045. Multi language code block would already indicate the language in the header.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann Not necessarily. There are far more many programming languages than there are highlighting languages supported. I tend to add HTML highlighting when the there’s code that’s a mix of HTML and a preprocessor language, for example, such as Blade (which can sometimes be closer to PHP).